# Подключение клиента через браузер в tcp/ip

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Вот код сервера на nodejs:

```js
var net = require("net");
var clientPeopleSockets = [];
var serverPort = 8124;
var idClientPeople = 1000000000;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
 //генерация ид пользователей
 idClientPeople = idClientPeople +1;
 //присваивание ид сокету
 socket.socketId = idClientPeople;
 clientPeopleSockets.push(socket);

    console.log('Клиент подключился id: '+idClientPeople);

 socket.on('data', function (data) {
  //убираем всякие переносы сторки и т.д могут быть ошибки криво все
  var dataClient = data.toString('utf8'); 
  dataClientNew = dataClient.replace(/[\r\n]/m,'');//***************** del
  dataClientNew = dataClientNew.substring(0, dataClient.length - 1);//********** del
  var coordMouse = dataClientNew.substr(0,5);//************ del
  var commandItString = dataClient.split(',');
//вывод объекта в консоль console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
//jsonDate = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
//console.log(jsonDate);
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  if (commandItString[0] == '100') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == idClientPeople) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write(clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '101') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].remouteUserId = idClientPeople; //ид пользователя суппорт записывается в объект пользователя к которому подключаются
     console.log('id: '+clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId+'--> '+' remouteUserId: '+clientPeopleSockets[i].remouteUserId);
    } 
   }
  }
  //test------------------------------------------------
  else if (commandItString[0] == '102') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('102'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '103') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('103'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '104') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('104'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '105') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('105'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '106') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('106'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '107') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('107'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '108') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('108'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else if (commandItString[0] == '109') {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == commandItString[1]) {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write('109'+commandItString[2]+'\n');
    } 
   }
  }
  else {
   for(i=0; i<clientPeopleSockets.length; i++) {
    if (clientPeopleSockets[i].socketId == '1000000002') {
     clientPeopleSockets[i].write(data);
    } 
   }
  }
  //----------------------------------------------
 });
 socket.on('end', function () {
        var i = clientPeopleSockets.indexOf(socket);
        clientPeopleSockets.splice(i, 1);
    });
});
server.listen(serverPort, function() {
    console.log('Сервер запущен на порту '+serverPort);
});
```

К этому серверу подключаются клиенты из приложения и обмениваются данными. Необходимо добавить получение данных из приложения в браузер. Подскажите как правильно это можно реализовать? На socket.io можно будет как то получить если да киньте небольшой примерчик. Или может через браузер можно как то подключиться напрямую в tcp/ip?

Comment: К вопросу не относится, но я бы вам посоветовал избавиться от этих `if else`, за место этого заведите объект `action` и там пропишите поведение, ключ, будет равен id команды, и далее этого легко использовать `action[commandIdString]()`, намного лучше будет

Comment: ок спс обязательно исправлю это тестовый код... проверял будет ли вообще работать )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выберите наиболее приятный для вас способ:

**1. Router - проще** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/router#api)

На сервере ставите: `npm install router`

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.end('индекс');
});
router.get('/путь1', function (req, res) {
  res.end('данные1');
});
```

На клиенте просто отправляете запрос на `myserver.com/путь1`, в окошке выведет `данные1`

**2. Socket.io - сложнее** (http://socket.io/docs/#)

На сервере ставите `npm install socket.io`:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (data,sendBack) {
        ...//какие-то вычисления
        sendback(123); //возвращаем данные
    }
}
```

На клиенте скачиваете и подключаете скрипт socket.io.js, затем делаете:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.emit('data',data,funciton(dataBack){
    //получаем данные от сервера
    console.log("Сервер вернул:",dataBack); //выведет 123
})
```

Количество аргументов для `sendBack` задаете сами, важно чтобы на клиенте callback принимал столько же. Например в NodeJS часто отправляют первым аргументом ошибки, вторым - данные, упакованные в массив или объект

Comment: Хм... то есть код как на сервере примерно, а какие библиотеки подключать в хтмл страницу )  на клиенте ? ) Или ее нужно тоже расположить на сервере ? и как подключить ) ? собственно много вопросов так как в ноде только разбираюсь еще....

Comment: http://socket.io/docs/#

Comment: можете хоть кратко описать для новичка что должно быть?

Comment: то есть через socket.io я могу подключаться смело ? или на сервере мне тоже придется продключать socket.io если так то мои приложения перестанут работать так как не умеют работать с socket.io правильно ?

Comment: Да, можете смело. Добавил в ответ немного деталей для начинающего. И советую попробовать примеры кода из их документации)

Comment: мне просто непонятно как socket.io и var net = require("net"); будут работать на одном порту и обрабатывать данные ) ?

Comment: Грубо говоря - разные заголовки. Socket.io ищет запросы по своим признакам и обрабатывает их. Все что он не обработает - это прочие запросы. И их может обработать например router при обработке запросов вида `example.com/ads/qwe`. Что не обработает и он - то можно обработать по дефолту и отослать 404 ошибку

Comment: Или даже сделайте все через https://www.npmjs.com/package/router, он, вероятно покажется проще)

Comment: то есть мне как я понимаю нужно сделать будет так:
`router.get('/message', function (req, res) {

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
})`

Comment: нет, выберите один из этих подходов

Comment: я уже ничего не понимаю ) По маршруту я буду использовать socket.io а в остальных случаях require("net") правильно ?

Comment: Я хочу те данные которые сервер получает по TCP обрабатывать их и передавать в браузер клиенту! Причем данные идут в стриме....

Comment: Эмм... если хотите сохранить net-овские стримы - тогда `socket.write(data)` https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback